# Restart NodeJS app running in docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile, containers

I have a nodejs app running in several docker containers in production mode. One of them is running backend app.

I want to know how to force this container to restart on some event programatically( for example system time has changed)? I need the same behaviour just as I would type ‘docker restart container-name’. The docker restart policy is set to always.

Thank you,

Tried process.exit() but not sure why docker daemon is not restarting

Comment: Can u share your docker file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run your container with this command:

```
 docker run -d --restart unless-stopped [Container_name]
```

with `unless-stopped` flag your container will restart automatically unless you stop it manually.

With this approach you can stop your `Node js` process using `process.exit()` and your container will restart.

For more info head to [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) page